# Link module: Confused about how to use link fields

Tags: navigation

I got the Link module because I thought it would help me manage links in my pages. But I have the following two problems:

- When I enter links in the "Links" form on the page-editing page (the functionality that appeared after installing the Link module), all this seems to do is put a list of those links at the bottom of the page. It doesn't seem to give me any way to place those links where I need them in the text of the page. Am I missing something?

  I thought that one advantage of using this module was going to be that I could use defined links on different pages, so that when a URL goes bad and I need to update it, all the links to that URL would change automatically. But all I see is the ability to define links separately and independently on any page they need to appear on. Again, am I missing something?

I also installed and enabled CKeditor and File (Field) Paths. From what I read, I thought that at least CKeditor would interact with the Link module to do what I needed. But when I click on the editor's link button after installing the Link module, it still only allows me to manually enter the data for a link.

I thought that managing links data (and other repeated content) from a database would be one of the major advantages of using a system like Drupal. Am I trying to do it the wrong way, or was I mistaken that this can be done?

Thank you.

(Note, I'm not talking about user-entered content here. Although there might be a forum on one of the sites, the vast majority of content will be entered and updated by one or two administrators.)

(And I suppose Views could do what I'm talking about for structured output, like a table, but I'm talking about links that need to appear on arbitrary strings of text anywhere in a page.)

Comment: _But all I see is the ability to define links separately and independently on any page they need to appear on. Again, am I missing something?_ No you're not missing anything, that's the only purpose of the link module. It doesn't create a library of links that you can then re-use, it literally provides a field that takes care of validation and has other features related to URLs. I don't know of anything that would let you magically update every link in every place on your site, there are just too many ways to get links onto pages

Answer (score 2):

you have mistaken the link module, it doesn't work as you are thinking, it will not place links wherever you want.
It is just to add the link with content not within the content body.

CKEditor will provide you with the options to format the content including links, but there is no interaction between CKEditor and Link module.

If you want to set custom URL's, you need to use Pathauto module.